# Fanfic where Hermione finds out she's a Zabini, marries Draco, has a fight with him, and flees to Italy

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, dramione

I'm looking for the name of a dramione fanfic, where Hermione finds out she's a Zabini and that she has to get married to Draco. They get married but they fight and Hermione moves to Italy with some other Zabini family members.

Basically, Draco feels a burn on his ring (which means Hermione is/trying to cheat on Draco) and he rushes to Italy. Blaise bans Draco from Italy and tries to keep him away from Hermione but Draco finds a way to buy a house next to Hermione and move in. He tries to get Hermione to talk to him so he could have her back as his wife.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Which site did you read this masterpiece on?

Comment: https://www.fanfiction.net/s/5629521/3/The-Pureblood?

Comment: https://www.fanfiction.net/s/8146545/1/Mudblood-to-Pureblood?

Comment: http://archiveofourown.org/works/1015125/chapters/2015872 probably not. It doesn't match other points.

Comment: I read that as "Hermione finds out she's a Zamboni" and I giggled like an idiot for an hour.  I acknowledge that this comment is not helpful, but I needed to tell someone.

Comment: @MagikarpMaster I read zucchini...

Comment: I thought [Zoombini...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Journey_of_the_Zoombinis)

Answer (score 9):

This is most likely [Blood Curses and Malfoys](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/3809888/1/Blood-Curses-and-Malfoys) by [Nebel Engel](https://www.fanfiction.net/u/696258/Nebel-Engel)

> "Do you think you are the only one with problems, Granger?" Draco
>   stood in front of her, anger written all over his face. DMHG Set after
>   Voldermort's defeat, Hermione and Draco must face an arranged
>   marriage, their families, and each other. Rated: Fiction T - English -
>   **Drama/Romance - Hermione G., Draco M.** - Chapters: 35 - Words: 123,686
>   - Reviews: 809 - Favs: 903 - Follows: 471 - Updated: May 15, 2010 - Published: Sep 30, 2007 - Status: Complete - id: 3809888

### Disclaimer: I have only skimmed through the story.

The elements that I have found that match are:

1. **`Hermione finds out she's a Zabini`**: Blaise is Hermione's brother
2. **`gets married to Draco`**: She gets married to Draco (seems like unwillingly) right in the beginning of the story
3. **`They get married but they fight`**: Blaise angrily confronts Draco on why Hermione left for her Grandparent's house
4. **`Hermione moves to Italy with some other Zabini family members`**: Hermioni moves to Italy to Zabini family manor
5. **`Draco finds a way to buy a house next to Hermione and move in`**: One of the things Draco plans to do in Italy is find a place nearby Zabini Manor
6. **`Blaise bans Draco from Italy`**: Draco cannot use floo power to reach Zabini Manor as the Zabinis' seemed to have banned him from the whole province (they are very influential)

Moreover, a scene is present in which **a ring burns on Draco's finger, which means Hermione is cheating on him** (after which he decides to rush to Italy, and finds out the Zabinis' had banned him from their province)

Comment: Does that sound like a sort of inverse _Twilight 2_ to anyone else?

Comment: @Gallifreyan One would have to have watched *Twilight 2* to know the answer to that question, wouldn't one?

Comment: may be he read the book